# Error with prepareForSegue “”unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value“”

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to pass data from a one view controller to the next view controller with prepareForSegue function. 
When I run the app and click on the button, my app crashes and I get this message "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value". I've tried many variations for the prepareForSegue function to pass the data but it would never appear on the next view controller.

Here is my code. First view controller:

```
class DiceViewController: UIViewController {

@IBAction func pressed(sender: AnyObject) {

    print("Button pressed")
    performSegueWithIdentifier("fromDice", sender: self)  
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()



}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if let hvc = segue.destinationViewController as? GameViewController {
        if let identifier = segue.identifier {
            switch identifier {
                case "fromDice": hvc.moveBy(2)
            default: break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Second view controller:

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
```

}

```
func moveBy(moveBy: Int) {

    print("move by \(moveBy)")
    var index = moveBy - 1
    activePlayer.center = levelButtons[index].center

   }

}
```

Console output:

Button pressed

move by 2

fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: Could you tell me about this line
activePlayer.center = levelButtons[index].center

Comment: Set an exception breakpoint.  See which line has the problem.  Look at what is nil.  Figure out why.

Comment: Hello. activePlayer is a UIImageView and levelButtons is a UIImageView array. Declared like that: var activePlayer: UIImageView! and var levelButtons: [UIImageView!] = []

Comment: I find where is the bug. I have two segue. First GameViewController to DiceViewController and second from DiceViewController to GameViewController. I have some initial setup in GameViewController and when I segue back from DiceViewController it creates a new GameViewController instance that's whyI get this error. Is there any way to return to the old GameViewController instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prevent the crash from happening by safely unwrapping levelButtons[index].center with an if let statement.

```
if let centreA = levelButtons[index].center{
    activePlayer.center = centreA
}
```

You need to debug for why you are getting nil.
Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I implemented unwind segue. And now I am able to return to my old GameViewController instance, and it solved the problem.